# Android 4 crash on BufferedReader?

Tags: android, json, bufferedreader

i've got this code which work fine on android <4:

```
        try{
            URL url = new URL("http://www.mysite.com/data.php");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            while((testo=in.readLine()) != null){
                testo2+=testo;
            }
            in.close();
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(testo2);
            button.setText(jObject.getString("n"));
            textView1a.setText(" "+jObject.getString("so"));
            textView1b.setText(jObject.getString("tc")+" ");
        }
        catch(MalformedURLException e){
            System.out.println("1");
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("2");
        }
        catch(JSONException e){
            System.out.println("3");
        }
```

but in android >4 doesn't work, it crash the app.
i don't know why, but it seems crashing on bufferedreader.
my url return a string like

```
{"n":"788531","so":"412848","tc":"609774","is":"14270","di":"55.257953749124"}
```

which i parse as json.

Comment: I hope you're fetching that data on non-UI thread

Comment: r u use this code in thread / AsyncTask?

Comment: How does it crash? LogCat please!

Comment: this is an old project (my first), and this code it's written in the onCreate.
but it have always worked....
this is the logcat:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/16047047/log.txt

Comment: i've putted this in an external function and nothing changed